# Magento issue with external mod "Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous"

Tags: php, mysql, magento, mysql-error-1052

```
$select->joinLeft(
       array('order_table' => $collection->getTable('sales/order')),
       'order_table.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',
       array('admin_user_id' => 'admin_user_id')
);
```

in a custom magento module that is causing the error

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous
```

commenting out this code allows magento to run correctly, the code is located in an observer

```
    public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        $select = $collection->getSelect();
        $select->joinLeft(
           array('order_table' => $collection->getTable('sales/order')),
               'order_table.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',
            array('admin_user_id' => 'admin_user_id')
        );
    }
```

Could anybody advise a fix, this is not my code or my module, and I don't fully understand everything it is doing.

I am guessing it adds a field to a table and populates it then allows you to search using it using the order page.

Thanks in advance.
-T

Comment: somewhere there's a call to add `created_at` to the query's `where` clause, but you've got 2+ tables involved in the query that both have a `created_at` field, so you need to specify the field as `tablename.created_at` to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: where would a module typically add this where clause as it sounds like that's what I need to edit, though looking through all the files I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched every where for this by i am not getting any exact result which will help me in this. But now i am with the result of why such thing is happening.It’s simple as it is saying “Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column ‘created_at’ in where clause is ambiguous”, means it is finding a another created_at field. because when we adding or joining the other table then it has also a field named as created_at. So what is the solution for this?

Any idea……………

Its simple just told magento that created_at is of the main_table not of my custom table, how can you do so, i will tell you the full procedure.

Step 1. Find the below code in the sales order grid.php file

`$this->addColumn('created_at', array( 'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'), 'index' => 'created_at', 'type' => 'datetime', 'width' => '100px', ));`

Step 2. in the second step just replace the code with below one.

```
$this->addColumn('created_at', array( 'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'), 'index' => 'created_at', 'type' => 'datetime', 'width' => '100px', 'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at', ));
```

Have you find what i have changed in the code, not you, ok let me explain. in this code i have added the following line:

```
'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at',
```

thinking of what’s the use of the following line, here created_at column of sales order grid find created_at from the main the collection .But we are getting twice created_at in the collection.So i have added the following line that this created_at is of the main table sales_flat_order not of the other table.

That’s the process

for more info you can visit the blog

http://www.webtechnologycodes.com/integrity-constraint-violation-1052-column-created_at-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous/

Comment: but your changes is in core, I tried to overload block and its overloaded successfully but we can't change/add same column which is already in parent.

Comment: i have moved the file to local then doing changes ,if you want to do it by creating a module then just override the block grid file and add the code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `'sfo_created_at' =>'sfo.created_at'` which will rename the `sales_flat_order.created_at` to `sales_flat_order.sfo_created_at` (you could also just remove that field from the select)

```
$collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('sfo' => 'sales_flat_order'),
    'main_table.entity_id=sfo.entity_id',
    array('sfo_created_at' =>'sfo.created_at', 'sfo.status')
);
```